# Как сделать отправку почты на почтовый ящик mail.ru?

Tags: php

Как сделать отправку почты на почтовый ящик mail.ru? Пробовал с помощь функции mail php, почта не приходит не в папку спам, не во входящие. На другие почтовые ящики почта приходит gmail.com, yandex.ru тоже приходит. Почта на хостинге настроена правильно.

Comment: Раз на другие приходит, значит код правильный.

Comment: Покажите код, для примера...

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что почта на хостинге настроена правильно? Домен у вас куплен, DKIM, SPF и DMARC подключены и проверены?

Answer (score 0):

Если во **From** указан ящик на mail.ru, то такое письмо не будет доставлено, такая политика этой службы. Используйте [SMTP сервер](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp), для гарантированной доставки почты, либо указывайте почтовый ящик на другом домене.

Comment: Пробовал во From указать почтовый ящик в другом домене, почта все равно не приходит

Comment: По мимо from есть еще заголовки типа ReplyTo и прочее, ящика на mail.ru не  должно быть в заголовках вообще (кроме to)